# Disable right click on html5 audio element

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are approaches for the video element but I can't find any for the audio element. Here's what I've tried.

```css
audio {
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<audio class="audio" controls controlsList="nodownload">
            <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
         </audio>
<script>
  $(document).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

Any ideas how I can prevent users from right clicking the audio element. Also, any ideas for how to effectively [outline the audio element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156596/outline-html5-audio-element?noredirect=1#comment109932056_62156596) if you have experience would be appreciated there too.

Comment: Why would you ever want to prevent someone from right clicking the audio element?  If you have some specific UI treatment, you should implement it with your own elements and update them with JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `oncontextmenu="return false;"` seems to work when the JavaScript doesn't.